# Why is a part of the graph left out?

Tags: plotting

```
c = 0.7;
s = 1;
    sol = Solve[
       A == (Exp[(h + 2*c*A)/s] - 
           Exp[-(h + 2*c*A)/s])/(Exp[(h + 2*c*A)/s] + 
           Exp[-(h + 2*c*A)/s]), A, Reals];
    Plot[Evaluate[A /. sol], {h, -1, 1}, Exclusions -> None]
```

Hi everyone,

If `c` becomes larger than 0.5 there is a gap in the graph. It must be a kind of s-shape. Does anyone know how to correct this?

Many thanks, 
Steven

[image: graph]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Solve gives me error messages, isn't it the case for you?

Comment: @Kuba Yes, but then the solve is evaluated in the `plot`, hence me thinking setdelayed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mindless approach:

```
ContourPlot[
 A == (Exp[(h + 2*c*A)/s] - Exp[-(h + 2*c*A)/s])/(Exp[(h + 2*c*A)/s] +
      Exp[-(h + 2*c*A)/s]),
 {h, -1, 1},
 {A, -1, 1}
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Because at `Abs[h]<=0.1518`, there are multiple solutions:

```
sol[h_] := 
  Solve[A == (Exp[(h + 2*c*A)/s] - 
       Exp[-(h + 2*c*A)/s])/(Exp[(h + 2*c*A)/s] + 
       Exp[-(h + 2*c*A)/s]), A, Reals];

Show[Plot[A /. sol[h], {h, -1, 1}, Exclusions -> None], 
 Plot[{(A /. sol[h])[[#]] & /@ {1,2, 3}}, {h, -0.1518, 0.158}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, since

```
(Exp[(h + 2*c*A)/s] - Exp[-(h + 2*c*A)/s])/
(Exp[(h + 2*c*A)/s] + Exp[-(h + 2*c*A)/s]) // ExpToTrig

(* Tanh[(2 A c)/s + h/s] *)
```

the given equation is (on the assumption that all quantities are real)

```
h == s ArcTanh[A] - 2 c A
```

so that ParametricPlot may be used:

```
c = 0.7; s = 1;
ParametricPlot[{s ArcTanh[A] - 2 c A, A}, {A, -1, 1}, 
PlotRange -> {{-1.05, 1.05}, {-1.05, 1.05}}]
```

[image]